# How to get the latest row by key in pouchdb?

Tags: pouchdb

Each data in the db has a key `createTime`, how can I get the piece of data with the latest createTime?

Answer (score 0):

Look into "Mango Queries" using the PouchDB "Find" plug-in [Here](https://pouchdb.com/guides/mango-queries.html)